# Is there any way to get Office 365 Label from mail message using graph api or different api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

There is property in EWS Emailmessage.PolicyTag.RetentionId. I want to access this property using Graph API or any other API. Earlier i was fetching it directly from EWS but due to latest changes in Exchange protocols. Email Message id retrieve on IOS or android is no longer working with EWS. earlier it was working.

I have tried Graph beta version also but failed to retrieve it.

Comment: I've reached out to the pm who owns ews to microsoft graph transition. He should be able to help you here.

Comment: Graph currently does not have a way to retrieve the RetentionPolicytags. Can you explain the issue with EWS where you were unable to retrieve email messages?

Comment: We develop O365 Addin to save Email into SharePoint from any plateform like windows, ios, mac & android. Earlier we fetch message id from office JS and send it to EWS with access token. this scenario was working perfectly until March 19, 2019. on the same day Microsoft did changes in Exchange protocols, due to the reason, message id returned on IOS/Android no longer work with EWS. we shift to Graph API to get email properties and mime content. Now we stuck on retentionPolicyid since we are labeling the emails while saving to sharepoint library. @JeremyThakeMSFT Please help on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Managed Graph API library to achieve that. Here is code snippet:

```
SearchFilter isequalto = new 
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(MessageObjectSchema.Subject, "Re: edb0e580-6446-4b17-912a-44b1ea7509a1");
MessageView view = new MessageView();
ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MapiPropertyType.Binary, 0x3019);
view.PropertySet.Add(propDef);
var msg = await service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view, isequalto);
```

This will be within SingleValueExtendedProperties definition.

Link to library: https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi

You will get base64 binary blob which you have to convert to bytes and construct Guid from it:

```
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(propertyValue);
new Guid(data);

returns:
33506786-ed79-4239-94a6-3222b0e1ff76
```

Comment: Hey Ivan, Could you please explain the snippet ExtendedPropertyDefinition propDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MapiPropertyType.Binary, 0x3019);
view.PropertySet.Add(propDef); I need to get the rententionid

Comment: sure, that is Mapi Property Tag of the retention policy. It contains guid of the retention policy in binary format. With above code you are asking for additional extended property which is not part of the common schema. Check full example here: https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/wiki/Querying-ExtendedProperty

Comment: HI,

From exchange we are getting GUId as a RetentionId. but from GraphAPI it is returning binary value as retentionId. Now when we match this binary value with Sharepoint tags it doesn't match. I am able to get the complianceTag name using below query Id eq 'String {403FC56B-CD30-47C5-86F8-EDE9E35A022B} Name ComplianceTag'. Is there any way to get GUID with respect to this Tag.

Comment: I updated answer which include explanation and simple example.